# Statistical mode (Calculator Java)

Tags: java, calculator, mode

Well, I'm programming an arithmetic calculator using Java, and I've tried to implement a function that calculates the mode. The problem is that for some reason it's not working right. Here's the function:

```
public static String moda(Double[] valores){

    Double resultado = null;
    Integer contador = 0;
    Integer contadorFinal = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < valores.length; i++){

        contador = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j < valores.length; j++){

            if(valores[i] == valores[j]) contador++;
        }

        if(contador > contadorFinal){
            resultado = valores[i];
            contadorFinal = contador;
        }
    }

    return "La moda es " + resultado + " que se repite un total de " + contadorFinal + " veces.";
}
```

For some reason, it's always returning me the first value of the array (for example, if Double[] valores contains (4,7,7,8,8,8) it will return me 4); and the mode is always 1 as well.

I've been looking the code again and again, and for me it looks fine. Can you help me, please?

Comment: Well, you only have a single "count" variable.  How, in your example (4,7,7,8,8,8) could it know that 7 occurred two times and 8 occurred three?  You need one count variable per value in the array.

Comment: @markspace thank you for your answer! "contadorFinal" is the second counter.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that.  But at first I couldn't figure out what you're doing.  Your algorithm won't preform well on large data sets, you might look into how to do this in one loop (which was what my comment assumed).

Comment: One problem is that you're currently not actually counting values which only appear once in the array, because you're doing an equality check before incrementing `contador`. So for example, if there's only one instance of 35 in your array, the equality check will never evaluate to `true`, and 35 won't be counted at all. Only a problem if all the values in the array appear only once, but still good to fix!

Comment: And I agree with @markspace, if you want to take this code to the next level, rewrite it to run in O(n) instead of O(n^2).

Comment: @markspace I will look into it, so my code will be the best optimized it could be! Thanks a lot for your answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you are comparing `Double`, a **class**, by equality.  Use `double` or use `Double.compare()`.

```
for(int i = 0; i < valores.length; i++){

    contador = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j < valores.length; j++){

        if( Double.compare( valores[i], valores[j] ) == 0 ) 
           contador++;
    }

    if(contador > contadorFinal){
        resultado = valores[i];
        contadorFinal = contador;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @markspace! You're my savior, I've been like for hours looking this code :)

Comment: Fantastic answer, and excellent question as well. I've been baffled with this for the past 15 minutes too!

Comment: An interesting thing to note is that the original code would have worked had  ```Integer``` been used instead of ```Double```, because of java caching integers from ```-128 and 127```.